# How to get the app name in django logger

Tags: python, django, logging

I have this formatter for django

`FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"`

The file name i get is

`views.py`

Now that is confusing as its hard to see from which module is that views.py.

Is there any to get appname in logger formatter

Comment: And how do you get the filename? os.path.basename(\_\_file__)?

Comment: @ryuusenshi , it is available by default , i didn't do it manually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pathname` instead of `filename` in your logging configuration.

```
FORMAT = "[%(pathname)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
```

There are also other variables you can use — check the [`logging` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) for a list.

---

Note that if you're acquiring a `Logger` instance using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` (which is a common way to do it), you can also retrieve the module name (e.g. `myapp.views`) using `name`.

This is (arguably) better practice but will not work if you're doing e.g. `logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")` or `logger = logging.getLogger()`

Comment: Thanks for that. 1. where i can see what other variables i can use. any documentation. 2. my full path is very big. is there way i can modify using string replace. i mean using any callback

Comment: @JohnKaff There is a link to the documentation in my answer. That documentation lists the other variables you can use.

Comment: i wanted to use `__name__` but then i am not able to get my custom logger . then it goes to default file nut my custom file

Comment: @JohnKaff You might want to be using custom handlers instead of a custom logger. Typically, where to log is the handler's responsibility, not the logger's. Make sure you read the logging documentation.